# emacs display anomaly in Jupyter notebook terminal

Tags: terminal-emacs, jupyter

When I use emacs in Jupyter hub terminal to edit a file, emacs seems to always insert an extra sequence of characters:

```
0;276;0c
```

before the actual content.

Also, after exiting emacs, the terminal display is weird. All characters become underlined. `clear` doesn't solve the problem. Only `tput reset` restores display to the normal state.

This is with emacs 26.2 on Ubuntu 18.04. Jupyter hub is TLJH as of Sep 2019.

Does anyone know how to fix the display issue?

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  What is your `$TERM`? When I tried with our jupyterhub, it was `xterm`.

Comment: @suvayu Mine was `xterm` too. uname is `4.15.0-60-generic #67-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 22 16:55:30 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`. Ubuntu 18.04 server.